# An error stopped replication agent from running

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, merge-replication

'm running a merge replication between two databases everything was fine. Starting from yesterday i'm getting this error message from replication job at Run Job step :

```
Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. String or binary data would be truncated. [SQLSTATE 22001] (Error 8152).  The step failed.
```

What reasons can cause this error message ?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

A very very long stored procedure caused the problem as the replication went to update Altered procedures to the subscriber the changes. the column responsible for taking the Alter script was just (4000) characters capacity then the Alter script for this particular procedure didn't fit. rare case but happened !